# Get magnet link to open with download center on LAN connected nas

Tags: networking, mount, samba, transmission

I currently i get my magnet links to open in "transmission" on my laptop with which i browse the internet.

Instead i would prefer the magnet links to (automatically open by "download center" on my LAN connected (asustor) nas.

is there a simpel way to do this? Samba maybe.. but even then ???

Currently i copy the link adres and then manual paste them in download center. This is very do-able but sometimes a bit of a hassle.

I understand that in theory the easiest way would be to browse on my nas to the magnet link.. but for many small reasons this is a even more of a hassle then the copy paste, since i would need an extra keyboard for which i don't have place and for which i really don't have much more need that this.

So if there is a way to fix by setting up software, then that would be ideal. I currently navigate through my nas by mouse... only, which works great.

to be true.. i really have no idea where to start with this so i haven't had much luck trying even googling on my own.

hope someone has an idea that could do this, or where to look.

Comment: Your NAS may have a different feature that's much easier, a folder where you can upload the torrent files, instead of using magnet links. That folder is in a network share

Comment: this is true.. but this has two minor problems. 1)  i  download to my download folder on my laptop.. which means still some copy paste. 2) not all sites give the torrent files available, while they do give magnet links. (the bay for example, or i must be blind)

Answer (score 0):

i resently found out that this is possible via transmission remote 
(this should work since download center is transmission based )

Unfortunately i will still need to figure out how exactly!
at the moment i don't have time for that.. but i will edit this answer as soon as i have found out.